# Ruby Array Infinitely Referencing itself

Tags: ruby, infinite-loop

A future classmate of mine brought this up a while ago, but we are all pretty new to ruby, and can't seem to find any explanation online. Hope someone here can explain.

[image]

As displayed in the image, when declare `h` as an empty array, and assigning the first element `[0]` as itself `h`, it ends up returning something like `[[...]]`. We are aware of that everything in Ruby are objects, this case the object_id remains the same regardless how deep we dive into `h`, so I'm assuming that it's referencing itself indefinitely.

Could someone give a more detailed explanation on what's going on here?

Edit: What would be a correct term for `...` inside `[[...]]`?

Thanks!!

Comment: it seems that you have it quite figured out. what is your question?

Comment: @UriAgassi I wasn't sure if that was the correct explanation. I'm wondering why Ruby lets this happen. What would be a more formal description?

Comment: Well, it is correct, and it is not problematic, as long as you are not trying to serialize it. Ruby lets this happen for the very simple reason that _it can't prevent this_ (even if it wanted). data structures may have loops, you can't prevent that, and sometimes the logic calls for that. Array's `to_s` is smart enough to prevent the console from hanging when it is called, which is a nice touch :-)

Comment: the `...` is a simple "here there be dragons" by the default serializer of arrays. I wonder if you can fool it by building a more complex data structure...

Comment: The original question was about Hash actually, which returns `h = { {...} => {...} }`, I found out array was behaving the same way. the hash actually have `h.keys[0], h.values[0], h` all equal to each other.

Comment: BTW serialization to YAML works: `a.to_yaml #=> "--- &1\n- *1\n"`.

Comment: "…" is called [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis). It's used in mathematics to indicate repeating values, e.g. 1, 2, 3, …

Comment: Ellipsis is also used in English and many other languages to indicate a missing part of speech, as in "Firyn wrote in his question: 'We are aware of that everything in Ruby are objects, […] so I'm assuming that it's referencing itself indefinitely.'" (Although note that *technically*, this is not *quite* an ellipsis, because an ellipsis (…) has a somewhat different spacing in between the three dots than simply three dots in row (...)).